# Problem with file permissions in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

So, I've copied the install tree of a site I'm developing to another machine. After updating settings.php to the proper db and base_path, and making sure that the file permissions for /sites/default/files/ are set to 755 (chmod -R 755 files), the file settings page (Configuration -> Media -> File System) insist that "The directory sites/default/files exists but is not writable and could not be made writable." I've experimented with 777 permissions to no avail. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try chmod -v to make sure permissions were in fact being changed? Do you know that your new shell user account has access to change file permission?

Comment: @65Fbef05 I verified write privileges by creating a file from within the shell.

Comment: Are there currently any files in your /files folder?

Comment: @65Fbef05 Yes, all of the expected files are present.

Comment: What OS and version are you using? If it's a recent Linux distribution then - assuming you actually tested for the obvious mistakes first - it could be a MAC implementation that's causing this (most probably either SELinux or AppArmor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change ownership of the files directory to apache, or whatever your web user is.

chown -R apache.apache files

If you don't have access to change ownership for some reason, then making all files recursively writable should work.

chmod -R a+w files